# Is the sentence "I hail my praise in your daily sandbox activities" grammatcally correct?

Tags: grammar

Is the sentence, "I hail my praise for all of your daily sandbox activities" grammatically correct?

Comment: You're hailing your own praise...?  That's what it sounds like. :-)

Comment: Yours makes the second distinct example of "hail my praise" I see in a Google search. 'He was showered with praise for all of his ...' is fine, but this is outlandish. Possibly as 'grammatical' as _Colorless green ideas sleep furiously_, but equally outlandish.

Comment: You might want to leave hailing for cabs and ships.

Comment: As @Edwin says, it’s _grammatically_ correct, but it doesn’t make any sense. The version in the body of your question (with _for_) makes at least a little sense, but the version in the title, “I hail my praise in your daily sandbox activities”, is utter nonsense. A person’s sandbox activities (whatever that may be—playing with plastic buckets and shovels, presumably?) is not a place where you can hail anything, least of all your own praises.

Answer (score 1):

Oxford Dictionaries (not OED) gives several meanings of the verb ***hail***

It can mean 'to call out to (someone) to attract attention' e.g. *I hailed her in English* or *I hailed a taxi*.

It can also mean *to praise* (someone or something).

So the expression *I hail my praise* is interesting. If you are using *hail* in the first sense it means *I call out my praise for your sandbox activities, in order to attract your attention*. Somehow I don't think that is what was meant.

If you are using 'hail' in the second sense, meaning praise, you would normally say *I hail your sandbox activities*. It would be extravagant as it would be in the same sense as saying *I hail the rescue workers who saved the man's life*. *Praise* would be implied, so you would not need to use the word.

But, despite the superfluity of expression which it carries, *I hail my praise for* sounds elegant. I would be interested to know where you saw it!

Answer (score 0):

The verb 'to hail' in this sense (i.e. 'to salute') though not quite archaic is usually reserved for situations of some pomp and circumstance. You might hear it in a politician's speech, say.

But if you wanted to use it grammatically (understanding that it would be understood as a sort of mock-serious extravagance) it would be:

*I hail you for all of your daily sandbox activities.*